# Request Object in PHP cURL

Tags: php, web-services, curl

I am attempting to consume a .NET webservice that is requesting a RequestObject of options and I have no idea how that works in cURL. Does anyone know?

For this webservice: https://uat.petfirsthealthcare.com/pfh.service.webservices/coreservice.svc/json/GetBreedList I need to send a Request Object 'CoreServiceGetBreedListRequest' with a value SpeciesId of 1.

Here is what I have, but missing the value.

```
$request = 'https://uat.petfirsthealthcare.com/pfh.service.webservices/coreservice.svc/json/GetBreedList';
        $session = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_URL, $request);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,3);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
        $response = curl_exec($session);
        curl_close($session);
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Found a hint since my SOAPCLient test failed.

Any service method that has no parameters will use a HTTP GET action, while those methods with parameters will use the HTTP POST action in order to send the parameter data to the service.

Answer (score 2):

That is a SOAP service, not a REST service. Although you can probably consume it anyways using curl() by reading the WSDL definition and by trial and error, it is much easier to consume it using the [SOAP libraries of PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/book.soap.php).

Use the SoapClient class. When it asks for a WSDL file, just pass:

https://uat.petfirsthealthcare.com/pfh.service.webservices/CoreService.svc?wsdl

Or download it, upload it to your server and set the path (but if the service changes, you may find issues).
That file will give the SoapClient class the available methods and required parameters (and parameter types) to make the correct requests to the service. Watch out parameter types, as PHP tends to cast anything to string, and the SoapClient class is picky about parameter types (if the WSDL states it must be an integer, it may fail if you send a string, even if it is "3").

Comment: I am getting back object(stdClass)#2 (1) { ["GetBreedListResult"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["Breeds"]=> NULL ["Error"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (1) { ["ErrorText"]=> string(23) "Request can not be null" } } }  for a result to this:
$client = new SoapClient("https://uat.petfirsthealthcare.com/PFH.Service.Webservices/CoreService.svc?wsdl");
$result = $client->GetBreedList(array('SpeciesId'=>'1'));
var_dump($result);

Comment: It looks that you are doing it right, but the service has some kind of internal issue. I guess you got a valid SpeciesID from some source. Even calling methods that no require parameters fails. (checked from http://www.soapclient.com/soaptest.html ). Can you get in touch with the service sysadmin/developer? There is little to no documentation on that service. Try casting SpeciesID to int, array('SpeciesId'=> (int)'1').

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use cURL, you have to use CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER and pass an array of content type application/json as well as the content length.

In CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS you also send a properly formatted request like this:

`$object = json_encode(array('Speciesid' => 1));`

the content length is = `strlen($object)`